# how can i get function list in a module in julia

Tags: function, module, julia

i want to get the function list in a julia module.

this is my test code:

```
module m

function foo(x::Int)
    s = 0
    for i = 1:x
        s += i/2
    end
    return s
end

end

for nm in names(m, all=true)
    println(nm)
end
```

i get this :

```
#eval
#foo
#include
eval
foo
include
m
```

it has something i donot know.

the answer about it in stackoverlow is too old and doesnot work.

how can i get my function list in the module and if i get the symbols how can i get the functions according to the symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[x for x in names(m, all=true) if getproperty(m,x) isa Function && x ∉ (:eval, :include)]
```